How Can I Display All Lint Errors and Warnings in VS Code Without Opening Each File?
When I run nx run-many -t lint --all, I get a lot of warnings and errors in the terminal.
Is there a way to display all these errors and warnings in the Problems section of VS Code?
Currently, they only appear when I open each file individually, but I have hundreds of files. Opening them one by one isn't an option for me.
I updated settings.json as follows:
{
  "eslint.lintTask.enable": true,
  "eslint.debug": true,
  "eslint.lintTask.options": "-c ${workspaceFolder}/.eslintrc.json"
}

However, when I open the Problems section in VS Code, I still don't see all the errors and warnings from all files.
How do you implement eslint.lintTask.enable in your code?
I also tried running "Restart ESLint Server" from the command menu.
Any ideas?
